# Вычесть константу регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, visual-studio

Нужно в Visual Studio в строках вида

```
smth 456
```

уменьшить все числа на 24.

Хочу это сделать при помощи поиска и замены по регулярному выражению.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот ответ аналогичен [соседнему](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791329/178988), но использует более простые регулярки (причём, с другим хвостом) и работает в Visual Studio.

Про саму схему:

Для уменьшения числа на 1, если оно не заканчивается на 0, надо уменьшить его последнюю цифру на предшествующую. Поскольку в регулярных выражениях подобных сочетаний нет, то надо её где-то найти. Поэтому можно добавить хвост `~9876543210` к числу. Тогда по регулярке `(\d)(~\d*\1(\d))` у нас окажется заменяемая цифра в `$1`, уменьшенная цифра в `$3`, а хвост, который мы не хотим менять в `$2`. Получается замена на `$3`.

Но есть проблема с уменьшением нуля. Нам бы хотелось после него девятку, но ведь надо уменьшить ещё и предыдущую цифру. Мометим это восклицательным знаком. Меняем хвост на `~9876543210!9`, а в регулярке добавляем возможность его выбирать: `(\d)(~\d*\1(!?\d))`. Теперь для цифр 1-9 всё остаётся по-прежнему, а `0` превращается в `!9`.

В последнем случае нам надо сделать перенос. Вычитать единицу мы уже почти умеем, поэтому делаем аналогично, только в числе ориентируемся не на `~`, обозначающую конец числа, а на `!`, обозначающий необходимость переноса. Сам восклицательный знак мы должны выкинуть, но если потребуется ещё перенос, то у нас появится новый, поэтому эту замену надо повторять до тех пор, пока она применима. А вот и модифицированная регулярка: `(\d)!(9\d*~\d*\1(!?\d))` - восклицательный знак перед девяткой и необязательные цифры между ней и тильдой, обозначающей конец числа. Замена та же.

Так мы научились вычитать `1`. Чтобы вычитать по 10 или 100, надо просто в первой регулярке указать количество неизменных цифр перед тильдой:

```
  1:   (\d)(~\d*\1(!?\d))
 10:   (\d)(\d~\d*\1(!?\d))
100:   (\d)(\d\d~\d*\1(!?\d))
```

Регулярка для переноса уже умеет делать перенос из любого места:

```
(\d)!(9\d*~\d*\1(!?\d))
```

Все замены делаются на

```
$3$2
```

Ну и не забываем потом удалить сам добавленный хвост `~9876543210!9`.
Могут остаться лидирующие нули - их тоже стоит удалить.
Можно сделать это одновременно заменой `0*(\d+)~9876543210!9` на `$1`.

А вот и код для проверки вычитания 24:

```js
var reg01 = /(\d)(~\d*\1(!?\d))/
var reg10 = /(\d)(\d~\d*\1(!?\d))/
var reg2 = /(\d)!(9\d*~\d*\1(!?\d))/
var repl = "$3$2"
var tail = "~9876543210!9"
var last = /0*(\d+)~9876543210!9/

function sub24(s) {
  var s = s.replace(/$/, tail)

  for (var q=0; q<2; ++q) {
    s = s.replace(reg10, repl)
    for (var next; (next = s.replace(reg2, repl)) !== s; s = next);
  }

  for (var q=0; q<4; ++q) {
    s = s.replace(reg01, repl)
    for (var next; (next = s.replace(reg2, repl)) !== s; s = next);
  }
  
  return s.replace(last, "$1")
}

for (var x=25; x<2000; ++x) {
  if (sub24(x+"") !== "" + (x-24)) {
    console.error(x)
  }
}

console.log("Done!")
```

Answer (score 1):

> **По непонятной причине в VS это решение не работает :(**

Можно 24 раза из числа вычесть единицу. Для этого:

1. Дописываем в конец строк `~012345678!9`
2. Повторить 24 раза:

   - Делаем замену по схеме `5(?=~.*(4))`, а для нуля `0(?=~.*(!9))` на захватываемую группу (регулярки объединяем через `|`, группы просто конкатенируем).
   - Разбираемся с переносами аналогичной регуляркой из `0!(?=9.+(!9))|1!(?=9.+(0))|...` - повторяем замену до тех пор, пока есть что заменять.
3. Убираем хвост `~012345678!9`
4. Убираем лидирующие нули у чисел (не показано в сниппетах)

Вот код для генерации регулярок и проверка корректности такой замены:

```js
var reg1 = RegExp(Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>`${i}(?=~.*(${i?i-1:'!9'}))`).join("|"))
var reg2 = RegExp(Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>`${i}!(?=9.+(${i?i-1:'!9'}))`).join("|"))
var repl = Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>"$"+(i+1)).join("")
var tail = "~012345678!9"

console.log(reg1)
console.log(reg2)
console.log(repl)
console.log(tail)

function sub24(s) {
  var s = s.replace(/$/, tail)

  for (var q=0; q<24; ++q) {
    s = s.replace(reg1, repl)
    for (var next; (next = s.replace(reg2, repl)) !== s; s = next);
  }
  
  return s.replace(tail, "")
}

for (var x=25; x<2000; ++x) {
  if (sub24(x+"") != x-24) {
    console.error(x)
  }
}

console.log("Done!")
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Ну а поскольку 24 - это много, можно добавить одну точку и сделать 2+4 = 6 циклов замены:

```js
var reg01 = RegExp(Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>`${i}(?=~.*(${i?i-1:'!9'}))`).join("|"))
var reg10 = RegExp(Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>`${i}(?=.~.*(${i?i-1:'!9'}))`).join("|"))
var reg2 = RegExp(Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>`${i}!(?=9.+(${i?i-1:'!9'}))`).join("|"))
var repl = Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>"$"+(i+1)).join("")
var tail = "~012345678!9"

console.log(reg01)
console.log(reg10)
console.log(reg2)
console.log(repl)
console.log(tail)

function sub24(s) { debugger
  var s = s.replace(/$/, tail)

  for (var q=0; q<2; ++q) {
    s = s.replace(reg10, repl)
    for (var next; (next = s.replace(reg2, repl)) !== s; s = next);
  }

  for (var q=0; q<4; ++q) {
    s = s.replace(reg01, repl)
    for (var next; (next = s.replace(reg2, repl)) !== s; s = next);
  }
  
  return s.replace(tail, "")
}

for (var x=25; x<2000; ++x) {
  if (sub24(x+"") != x-24) {
    console.error(x)
  }
}

console.log("Done!")
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```